# What is the problem with my bash script and why isn't it working?

Tags: bash, bin

```
#! bin/bash
echo "Hello what is your first name."
   read name
if [ $name ]; then
   echo "$name, that's a funny name"
else
   echo "I asked for your name, you better answer me, i'll give you another chance, this time you better answer me, you understand, YES or NO"
read response 
   if [ $response ]; then
echo "Then tell me WHAT IS YOUR NAME"
   read name
echo "Finally, thank you, bye $name"
   else 
echo "Say goodbye to your family"
   fi
```

Comment: Try to indent your code correctly.

Comment: I miss a second `fi`.

Comment: To help debugging shell scripts, use https://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: When asking about a problem, you need to describe what the problem is. When does the problem occur? What does it do/not do, and how is that different from what you want? Do you get any error message(s) (if so, report the *exact* error message(s)). See the help entry on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `if [ $name ]`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be in your fist line

Change

```
#! bin/bash
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: This makes no difference.

Comment: @Cyrus A blank makes no difference, but `bin/bash` vs. `/bin/bash` (as is the case here) *does* make a difference.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Well spotted. That had escaped me.